# Filter data from timestamp by passing only part of date in sql

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to write query to filter data set from table by only passing part of date as year & month or quarter range & year
Passed value of (part of date) -> 2021-4 Or Q1-2021
But in table date has stored as 01-APR-21 1222.36643100 PM ASIA/COLOMBO

May I know how do I filter data?
I filtered data from like this but this is not I want.
-> Select * from A where CAST(A.startDate as DATE) like '%-APR-21'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Option 1: Use a date range

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   A
WHERE  DATE '2021-04-01' <= start_date
AND    start_date < DATE '2021-07-01'
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   A
WHERE  TIMESTAMP '2021-04-01 00:00:00 ASIA/COLOMBO' <= start_date
AND    start_date < TIMESTAMP '2021-07-01 00:00:00 ASIA/COLOMBO'
```

#### Option 2: Truncate to the start of the quarter

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   A
WHERE  DATE '2021-04-01' = TRUNC(start_date, 'Q')
```

#### Option 3: Use `EXTRACT`

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   A
WHERE  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) = 2021
AND    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date) IN (4, 5, 6)
```

*Note: While they will all work, only Option 1 would use an index on the `start_date` column. The second option would require a function-based index on `TRUNC(start_date, 'Q')` and the third option would require two function-based indexes on `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date)` and `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date)` (or a single composite index on both).*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the EXTRACT method can be useful.

For example in your case:

```
Select * from A 
where EXTRACT(MONTH FROM A.startDate) = 4
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM A.startDate) = 2021
```

USAGE

```
SELECT EXTRACT(<PART> FROM A.startDate);
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much @Erick8mm. May I know how to get range of dates. As example for quarter , i want to pass 1st quarter then should filter data from dates between 1st Jan - 31 March for given year